# Ubuntu Won't Install On Custom Build

Tags: installation

Just built my first computer, trying to install Ubuntu, when I tell my BIOS to startup from disk drive it says :

> "Please insert boot media into boot device"

So I insert my burned disc and my computer thinks for a few seconds and then prompts me again. Any idea why? Tried multiple times, burned two discs, I have even confirmed that my build works by swapping hard drives with the computer I'm currently using to post this, so I'm kinda out of answers right now and hoping you guys can help me find something I've done wrong, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried a different disc, or even using a USB?

Comment: Make sure your BIOS is set to boot from CD or USB, and that you correctly wrote the ubuntu installation image to the  disk.  just copying the  ISO to the disk won't work.  Use something like unetbootin

Comment: Your build information is nonexistent.  Please include some detail about your computer, such as motherboard, processor, optical driver, and graphics card (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with custom builds. its usually stems back to my CD-ROM. install from a usb stick, or a usb CD-ROM. also try a windows 7 disk just to see if it boots to the CD. also check to make sure you CD-ROM is actually a DVD-ROM. if your disk tray is a cd-rom, and not dvd, it won't boot from/read the dvd.

thanks
jmartin